# PHP Paypal Class

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Could anybody recommend a up-to-date class (or payment system) for handling paypal recurring payments with PHP?

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE: I ended up using the PaypalNVP class by Peter Reisinger. Unfortunately, that was a very long time ago and I can't seem to locate it online (the readme and class files had no URL - just the name). If you can find it, that's a great class and I highly recommend it.**

Comment: The PayPalNVP class may be found at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/paypal-nvp/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the freedom to pick a gateway, pick one that provides recurring billing services and APIs to us them.  I know [authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net) does.

You really, really, really, don't want to store credit card information.  Really.

If you want to do a "save my information" kind of thing, find a vendor that supports storing the card details for you.  [Braintree](http://www.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/credit-card-storage) does this, and I'm sure other vendors do as well.

Comment: Braintree also provides a PHP library: http://bit.ly/braintree-php . Disclosure: I work for Braintree.

Comment: I'm just picking the answer with the most up-votes. See my update for what I actually ended up using. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case you are still interested in one. This one is working really great and extremely easy to implement:

http://www.micahcarrick.com/04-19-2005/php-paypal-ipn-integration-class.html

Answer (score 2):

I published a class that really simplifies using the Paypal API, you can check it out [over on Binpress](http://www.binpress.com/app/php-paypal-api-class/20). I just recently added recurring payments support

Answer (score 1):

Paypal provides a very nice code snippet for processing paypal transactions, then it's just a matter of setting up a cron job that pulls from a DB what transactions to process.

Comment: Would I have to store CC information the DB?
Could you please provide a link to such snippets?
Thank you :)

Comment: You would have to store credit card information for a recurring payment like that, unless the paypal API now offers something like that, but it didn't last I was using it.  Here's the link you asked for https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code .

Answer (score 1):

PHP Payment Library for Paypal, Authorize.net and 2Checkout:

http://www.phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/

Comment: "basic usage only and do not contain options for recurring payments" - I am looking for a recurring payments supporting class