# how to integrate paypal plus login and payment in php code

Tags: php, paypal

I have created sandbox app and respective business & buyer accounts in paypal. Now want to integrate paypal plus on form submit that should allow user to make login and pay. 
But I am new to it, can anyone help me this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Paypal Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676758/php-paypal-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the integration guide for integrate PayPal Plus.

http://fiber.angelleye.com/forums/github/paypal-plus-rest-api/Integrating_PayPal_Plus_Vers._1.8.pdf

Comment: thx HK, do you have any sample code  ?

Comment: Not yet , But just follow the integration guide for the same .

Comment: okay, can you plz help me to summarize the things from page 13 to 16 in pdf. As I need user to pay with paypal using my from button 'purchase now'. How should I go for it, I m working in core php..

Comment: Its done thx..............

Comment: One question - On return Url -its giving me -'paymentId','token',PayerId . how can I get the Payment Status ? And till yet I didn't able to see any transaction in sandbox account.
Please let me know if is I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @Atul see the "Look up payment" page no 23

I hope its help for you..

Comment: @Atul Please follow  the "Look up payment" page no 23 ..

I hope its help for you.